# Dynamic Slash Command Options Based on Database Entries

Tags: python, mysql, database, pycord

I would like to add `options` to this `slash command` that change depending on **database entries**.

Example:

> userx has IMPJ and IMGR in the database with values "1" and "748", for the other entries `None`, so if they use the command "sell" the only options shown to them are "IMPJ" and "IMGR".

I tried the following:

```py
    @stocks.command(name="sell", description="Sell your stocks")
    cursor.execute("SELECT bank, IMAW, IMBG, IMGR, IMPJ, MACB, MAY FROM economy WHERE user_id = %s", (user_id,))
    user_data = cursor.fetchone()

    choices = []
    if user_data:
        bank_balance, imaw_quantity, imbg_quantity, imgr_quantity, impj_quantity, macb_quantity, may_quantity = user_data
        
        quantities = [imaw_quantity, imbg_quantity, imgr_quantity, impj_quantity, macb_quantity, may_quantity]
        items = ["IMAW", "IMBG", "IMGR", "IMPJ", "MACB", "MAY"]

        for quantity, item in zip(quantities, items):
            if quantity:
                choices.append(item)

    print(choices)

    @option("symbol", description="Choose what stock you want to sell", choices=choices)
```

But I got the following error:

> File "/GIS_Main/Cogs/economy.py",
> line 890
> cursor.execute("SELECT bank, IMAW, IMBG, IMGR, IMPJ, MACB, MAY FROM economy WHERE user_id = %s", (user_id,))
> ^
> SyntaxError: invalid syntax

I understand that it is because I am trying to run code between `@x.command()` and the `async def`, so I want to ask if it's even possible what I'm trying to do?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: what database would you be using?

Comment: MySQL but does that help?

Comment: Yes, it's related to your question